# How can I access app.locals within User model file?

Tags: node.js

I've created a file to hold some application wide configuration using app.locals. That config file looks like this:

**config/vars.js**

```
// App wide variables
module.exports = function (app) {

    app.locals.accessLevels = [
        {
            "levelName" : "Basic",
            "scrapes" : 3
        },
        {
            "levelName" : "Pro",
            "scrapes" : 10
        },
        {
            "levelName" : "Ultimate",
            "scrapes" : 99999
        }
    ];

}
```

I want to access the `app.locals.accessLevels` array within my user's model which is here:

**app/models/user.js**

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    local            : {
        firstName    : String,
        lastName     : String
        // more stuff, simplified here for the question
    }

});

userSchema.methods.remainingScrapes = function() {


    // === >>> I need access to app.locals.accessLevels here

    var today = new Date().yyyymmdd();
    var scrapes = this.local.scrapes;
    if (scrapes.length > 0) {
        scrapes.forEach(function(item, i) {
            if (today === item.date.yyyymmdd()) {
                return item.count;
            }
        });
    }
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Then, there is also my existing code to consider where I'm accessing the User model (e.g. routes.js) because if I change something in the user model file, I don't want it to break my routes.js file...

** app/routes.js **

```
// I have simplified this file and removed excess code, but the function below
// is using the User model, so I have kept it in to demonstrate what code I have

var User = require('../app/models/user');

module.exports = function(app, passport) {
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

        // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            return next();
        }
        // automatically login admin
        else if (app.locals.env == "development") {

            User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  'anthony.hull@gmail.com' }, function (err, user) {

                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                } else {
                    console.log("login", "defaulting to admin user log in");

                    // assign user to req.user with passport's login method
                    req.login(user, function(err) {
                        if (err) {return next(err); }
                        return next(null, user);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            res.redirect('/login');
        }



    }
}
```